# What are the infinitesimal generators of the Mobius transformation

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, mobius-transformation

I understand that the Mobius transformation $$f(t)=\frac{at+b}{ct+d}$$ is isomorphic to $SL(2)$ for $ad-bc=1$. I also know how to get the infinitesimal generators for the $SL(2)$ group. i.e. the trace-less matrices. But how can I get the infinitesimal generators of the Mobius transformation? I understand that I have to Taylor expand about the identity which corresponds to $a=d=1,b=c=0$, but I'm not sure how to do this. Do these generators correspond to the generators of SL(2) Lie algebra?

Comment: @Callum I understand that, but won't the infinitesimal generators of the Mobius transformation be functions? How can I obtain those?

Comment: What is your definition of the generators of the group of mobius transformations? Because to my mind they are exactly the Lie algebra elements by definition.

Comment: In my context, studying Lie groups and differential geometry, "infinitesimal generators" is often used when referring to a basis of the Lie algebra. Note that de Möbius group is not really SL(2,C), as any two matrices proportional to each other yield the same Möbius transformation: you are actually talking about $PSL(2,\mathbb{C}) = SL(2,\mathbb{C})/\mathbb{C}^*$, i.e., any two matrices proportional to each other are identified.

Comment: @topolosaurus Yeah I really mean $PSL(2)$. But I mean to get the generators of $PSL(2)$ we Taylor expand. Following the same procedure for the Mobius group, wouldn't that give us a basis composed of functions? How do you obtain those?

Comment: I am aware that Taylor expansion is a fruitful method, for example, to calculate the infinitesimal generators of some matrix Lie groups (like SO(2), for example). However, in differential geometry, the Lie algebra is seen as those tangent vectors of the Lie group at identity (so it is similar to Taylor expanding!). What I'd do is try to parametrize some curve $A(t)$ of elements in your group, imposing the relations from your group. You'll end up with your trace-free condition **plus** an extre one from the "identify prop. matrices" condition! If I can I'll write an answer.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3536059/finding-infinitesimal-mobius-transformations?rq=1) post will illustrate how to compute infinitesimal Möbius transformations, using precisely the "derivate the curve" method I described above.

Comment: I guess my main confusion arises because we want constraints on the parameters of the transformation and not $t$. So why consider a path $A(t).$

Comment: @topolosaurus I read your other answer but I'm still a little confused. I understand that placing the constraint that $ad-bc=1$ means $A$ is parametrized by three variables $a,b,c$ with $d=\frac{1+bc}{a}$. I'm a bit confused by your derivation. Shouldn't there be three infinitesimal generators instead of just one?

Comment: I should have been more explicit: $A(t)$ must be a curve in the group with $A(0)=1$, the identity element (explicitly, $a=d$, $b=d=0$ for your SL(2,C) matrices. Then, the derivative $\dot{A}(0)$ is an element of the Lie algebra: you will get constraints for the values of $\dot{a}(0),\dot{b}(0),\dot{c}(0)$ and $\dot{d}(0)$. Solving these equations will yield a set of generators: there should be three, as in the other post there are 3 free parameters (as $\dot{a}(0)+\dot{d}(0)=0$).

Answer (score 1):

> Do these generators correspond to the generators of the ${\mathfrak sl}(2)$ Lie algebra?

Of course they do. Expand the parameters around the identity, so $a= 1+\epsilon$, $d=1-\epsilon$, $b=\beta$, $c=\gamma$, where we ignore second and higher orders of the infinitesimal Greek parameters. So the infinitesimal transformations are a scaling,
$$
t\mapsto  {(1+\epsilon)t \over (1-\epsilon)}\sim t +2\epsilon t \leadsto \\
T_3=2t\partial_t;  
$$
a translation,
$$
t\mapsto t+\beta  \leadsto \\
T_+=\partial_t; 
$$
and a power rise,
$$
t\mapsto  { t \over \gamma t+ 1 }\sim t  -\gamma t^2  \leadsto \\
T_-= -t^2\partial_t. 
$$

Convince yourself these three *T*  generators close upon commutation, and normalize them suitably. Do you see how the unimodular group transformation near the identity,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1+\epsilon & \beta\\\gamma & 1-\epsilon  \end{pmatrix},
$$
is generated by the complete set of the three (traceless) Pauli matrices: $\sigma_3, \sigma_+, \sigma_-$?

Physicists and stringers subsume this into [Dyson-Maleev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holstein%E2%80%93Primakoff_transformation).